# Contact List doesn't show all contacts Galaxy S4 l9515

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-4, google-contacts

The problem bugging me is that when I go to the Contacts App, it show/display 55 contacts. According to the "Menu", it is set to show All Contacts.
But when I go to any App that share contacts (i.e. go to WhatsApp, open any chat and select Attach Contact) it shows such a big list of contacts that I estimate about 500 contacts easily. Some I have no idea how it got there, some others I think they're being listed because sometime in the last decade I sent them 1 single email from Gmail. I tried to go to http://www.google.com/contacts but there it only shows the 55 original contacts. Do I have to erase all emails I've ever sent to get rid of this giant list of contacts?

Comment: Had you enabled google+ people details synchronization?

Comment: No, should I? I only added my Google Account to the phone, I'm pretty sure it starts syncing on it's own, but I didn't manually added Google+ to it.

Comment: Download a third party contact manager to check if you actually have so many contacts. Contacts+ would be a nice choice.